# How to default to Docker Compose production configuration when connected to dedicated Docker Machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a project which is setup with Docker Compose. When me or anyone from my team is working on the project, getting everything running is just a `docker-compose up` away. We also have a Docker Machine ("default") associated with the production environment. So we just have to connect to the machine via:

```sh
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

and now deploying is exactly the same as getting everything running locally. Just a `docker-compose up`. I love this!

However, the Compose configuration is now split into three files:

- `docker-compose.yml`: general stuff. Applies for both production and local environment.
- `docker-compose.override.yml`: only applies in local environment.
- `docker-compose.production.yml`: only applies in production environment.

Conveniently, docker-compose automatically reads both `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` so in the local environment we can still run `docker-compose up` without additional arguments. In the production environment we need to be explicit though:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.production.yml up
```

This is much more verbose and it's easy to forget about the additional arguments when you are used to simply running `docker-compose up`. I which I had the seamless experience from before: Connect to the machine with a single command and then use the same commands as if you are in the local environment.

I found out that you can make docker-compose default to a different set of configuration files by setting the environment variable `COMPOSE_FILE`. So my go-to solution by now is running **two** commands when connecting to the machine:

```sh
eval $(docker-machine env default)
export COMPOSE_FILE="docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.production.yml"
```

This works! I can run `docker-compose up` in the production environment just like before.

Since `eval $(docker-machine env default)` too is doing nothing but registering environment variables, I was wondering if it's possible to permanently add this line:

```sh
export COMPOSE_FILE="docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.production.yml"
```

into the output of `docker-machine env default` so I'm back to running a **single** command when I want to connect to the machine.

If this is not possible (I couldn't find a source) is there a different approach to this problem?

Of course I could write a shell script which simply includes both commands but I would prefer an idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you just run the `docker-compose env` command without the `eval` wrapper, it will write out a series of shell commands.  You can wrap this with another script that runs `docker-compose env` and also adds your other settings

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# I am docker_production
docker-compose env default
echo 'export COMPOSE_FILE="docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.production.yml"'
echo 'PS1="PRODUCTION $PS1"'
```

If you run this script

```sh
./docker_production
```

it will print out shell commands that set up the environment; to actually have it take effect you can

```sh
eval $(./docker_production)
```

In the same way you can write a shell script that outputs the command to undo this

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# I am docker_development
docker-compose env -u
echo 'unset COMPOSE_FILE'
echo 'PS1="${PS1#PRODUCTION }"'
```

```sh
eval $(./docker_development)
```

Comment: I see... my dream goal would be a solution that doesn't look project specific. If an experienced docker-ist reads my documented instructions on how to run locally and how to deploy he should ideally see nothing he has never seen before. In case of your solution, he might wonder what's in this `docker_production` file there.

Comment: I think your question pretty clearly lays out the capabilities and limitations of the standard tools.

Comment: Ok, I can totally live with that. I was just wondering if there is a standard solution to this I'm not seeing.

Are you sure there isn't a (non-hacky) way to extend the output of `docker-machine env` though? It looks to me as if this could be somehow configured when the machine is created.